# How to handle empty Objects in API responses before rendering to page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I'm currently using Petfinder's api to build a side project in order to learn Node.

The problem is that Petfinder's api will sometimes return an empty object for specific fields that I might want to display on the page. So far, I've been checking against the existence of a non-empty object like so on point of generating the HTML:

```
<img class="pet-image" src="${Object.keys(pet.media).length !== 0 ? pet.media.photos.photo[3].$t : ""}">
```

But this code is quite ugly and I know that it shouldn't be done here. Plus, it would get quite cumbersome to always have to do this for non-required fields from the API response. What are some strategies on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are some strategies on how to handle this?

There are tools like [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) (from lodash) that let you get an object's property at a path and automate this - however generally it is not a great approach to have objects whose type you are not sure of in your code.

The most common and my favorite strategy would be to convert the object to a form you are familiar with at the call site (when the request arrives):

```
const someWeirdAPI = await fetch('./endpoint').then(x => x.json());
const result = {
  cake: someWeirdAPI.cake || "Default Cake",
  pets: someWeirdAPI.pets || [] // or some other default
  // ... etc
};
```

That way, you know that when you got the object inside your code it is always valid - you can also add properties when you translate between the API data transfer object and your domain layer objects (your logic).

Comment: Benjamin, that sounds like a good approach. I know that a lot of developers at my workplace actually use lodash in their Node application, so I might look into that. I do a have a follow-up question though: What do you mean by "objects whose type you are not sure of in your code."? I believe I could be reasonably sure of type in my response unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: @JasonChu if you have to guard something like: `pet.media.photos` then you are not sure what the structure of the object is. `pet.media` is an object that _might_ have a `photos` property but you are not sure of that and have to check at every usage site that may lead to messy code.